# Inner join - more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a code that will join together information from 3 tables and compare it with a "big table" and according to the comparison update a field in a test table. Look at the example:

Big Table:

```
    Employee_Id  status 
       2322         5
        222         3
        545         6
       4532         2
```

Table 1:

```
S_Id  status 
2322    7
```

Table 2:

```
S_Id  status 
222     3
```

Table 3:

```
S_Id  status
545     6 
4532    3
```

Test Table:

```
TE_Id  IsNotGood
2322      1 
4532      1
222       0
545       0
```

The id "2322" got 1 because the status in table 1 is not like the status in the big table and same for 4532.

I started writing this:

```
update Test Table
set isNotGood = 0
 with ids as (
    select distinct Employee_Id from (
    select Employee_Id,Status from  BigTable as B
    )  as T
    inner join table1 as W on W.S_ID = T.Employee_Id
    inner join table2 as K on K.S_ID = T.Employee_Id
    inner join table3 as R on R.S_ID = T.Employee_Id    
    )
```

I would be happy for your tips to finish this query.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have to have the CTE definitions **before** the update statement

Comment: Also, isn't this the exact same question you asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983755/inner-join-of-more-than-one-table

Comment: what is cte? 

And sorry, I posted another post because I didn't know how to respond with a code and thought pepole will not recognize the edit. I new here. Thank's.

Comment: CTE- [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: CTE (common table expression) is the "with ids" part in your query.

Comment: I know you are new here.  You are posting code with syntax errors and not defining the problem.  Fix the original post or both are going to get shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use an inner join unless the employee_id is in all the tables.

```
UPDATE Test
SET isNotGood = 1
WHERE te_id in (select employee_id
from [Big Table] bt
left join table1 as W on W.s_id = bt.employee_Id
left join table2 as K on K.s_id = bt.employee_Id
left join table3 as R on R.s_id = bt.employee_Id
where (bt.status <> W.status and W.status is not null) or (bt.status <> K.status and k.status is not null) or (bt.status <> R.status and R.status is not null);
```